# Is there a way to specify where XMLHttpRequest content is added?

Tags: html, get, xmlhttprequest

I've been using W3Schools' Javascript library to handle HTML includes onto other HTML pages. Everything has been going good, except I'm running into some formatting issues. When the include processes, it puts the HTML into the body tag when I'd prefer it into a different tag. I don't want my body tag formatting to impact the HTML content that's imported. I'm open to any solutions, but I'd prefer something that allows me to specify a specific tag in the HTML document to be imported into.

I've tried putting the Javascript call into the head or outside of the body tag but haven't had any luck.

Here's the code used by W3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

```
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>

<!-- import header -->
<div w3-include-HTML="./includes/header.html"></div>

<!-- import navigation bar -->
<div w3-include-HTML="./includes/navbar.html"></div>

<!-- Script to Handle W3Schools HTML Includes -->
<script>
  w3.includeHTML();
</script>
```

Thanks for the help! I'm hoping there's a good way to do this, otherwise I guess I can format my text outside of the body tag... That's far from ideal though.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to replace `<script> w3.includeHTML(); </script>` by `<script>includeHTML(); </script>` ?

Comment: Yep, no luck. The include no longer shows up, and there's an error.

Uncaught ReferenceError: includeHTML is not defined
    at (index):24